# issues with spark master webUI and eventLog

Tags: apache-spark, bigdata

We were running an ec2 cluster (6x m1.xlarge) with spark 1.1.0, and everything worked fine, yesterday I launched a new cluster (same specs) but with spark 1.3.1
and I'm having issues with eventLog.enabled true properties
been experiencing the same behavior as in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-6950. Even though jobs have already finished, the webUI history fails to build them and shows them as in progress. I checked and the *.inprogress file is still there.
I read the bug report in JIRA, it says 6950 was fixed in 1.3.1, but I keep getting this error every job I run, and I saw a comment from someone else with the same issue (6 days ago). Any ideas?

Comment: hitting https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-6107 . may be.  SPARK-6950  is marked as not reproducible

Comment: 6950 it's not the same as 6107, in 6107 they said it should be fix in 1.4.0 but it is regarding manually stopped jobs, in 6950 (and the issue i'm having) is with every single job i run, it doesn't matter if it was stopped or if it finished succesfuly

Answer (score 1):

Happens to me also on spark 1.3.1